# Solder paste not wetting at all

Tags: surface-mount, reflow, solder-paste

I have an issue with solder paste, I would like to know its origin so I can fix the problem and solder by components properly.

I use a lead free Sn42/Bi57.6/Ag0.4 solder paste, manufactured by ChipQuick.

[Here is the datasheet.](http://www.chipquik.com/datasheets/SMDLTLFP.pdf)

The syringe I'm using was opened three weeks ago and stored at ambient temperature until now. (I close it with the protective cap between each use, of course.)

I ran some tests before actually using it to solder components. I simply deposited several bits of it on a copper board, which I previously wiped with alcohol.

I have at my disposal a soldering oven (not some salvaged toaster, a real oven designed for this application).) However, it works like regular timer-ovens: set a time with one button, and set a temperature with another.

This is the process I used so far:

1. I put the board in the oven, at ambient temperature
2. I start the oven at 90°C and I wait one minute
3. I set it to 140°C and wait for two minutes
4. I set it for 180°C and wait for the solder paste to "melt" and get transformed to actual solder
5. Finally, just after the activation, I turn off the oven and open the door to allow a quick return to ambient temperature.

Problem is, I always end up with a nice sphere instead of observing spread solder across the copper face.
Exactly like this :

[image: this]

I want to know if I am doing something wrong during the process, or if this is linked to the storage conditions of the solder. Note that the manufacturer indicates a good "shelf life" but I don't know if it implies that the container should not be opened.

Comment: Can you post a picture with your culinary achievements?

Comment: I wanted to, but I can't take pictures on my workplace. Just imagine a perfect metal sphere on top of flat copper with flux around it. edit : I found an equivalent picture on google, I'm adding it

Comment: @MaximGi Did you check reflow profile in the datasheet? You didn't provide amount of time which it takes for the solder to melt, but it might be too slow.

Comment: The Google picture looks like a "cold solder joint". A cold solder joint is when there is enough heat to melt the solder but not enough heat/time to overcome the heat sink offered by the parts being soldered. Happens a lot where larger masses are being soldered such as relays etc.

Comment: Both AndrejaKo and Harvard have very good points. Does the datasheet specify the temperature and time required for this to melt? In your point 4 you say `wait for the solder paste to "melt" and get transformed to actual solder` while in other steps you mention actual time. How do you wait for it to transform? Is there a window on the oven? Usually lead-free solder has slightly higher melting temperature (again, **usually**, check datasheet) so maybe bump it up to 200C and leave it for a bit longer...

Comment: I would also recommend a thermocouple attached to the board to put a bit of truth into the temperature readings. The solder "melting" means it *just* reached 138C, not necessarily the peak 165C specified. Try cooking until it wets the pad.

Comment: "The solder "melting" means it just reached 138C, not necessarily the peak 165C specified" That may be the right answer ! I'm running some more tests today, I'll keep you guys in touch

Comment: @nurchi There is a window yes, and I just checked this afternoon : I am respecting the recommended profile. I cannot use leaded solder, I couldn't even order it if I tried to, its banned now. What I did today, was also to keep the temperature increasing above the maximum 165° to approx. 240°C and the solder finally wetted. Components (2012 (mm) resistors were apparently not damaged. Then, I think DerStrom8 gave the good answer : the copper is simply not heated enough. I think I will use a solder paste with higher melting point

Comment: The solder with higher melting point may need even higher temperature, the one you have might be perfect, you just might need to play with the profiles. Consider doing 200C-220C for an extra minute compared to the 165C. Or leave it at ~165C+ for preheat and then crank up to 220C-240C for the actual soldering. Or ... well, you get the idea :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My guess would be that the copper board is not being given enough time to heat up. Due to its thermal mass the copper heats up much more slowly than the solder, and the solder melts before the board reaches the correct temperature. If you choose a smaller piece of copper, or an etched PCB with less copper on it, or leave the copper board in the reflow oven longer, the solder will eventually flow as expected. It's probably just that the large thermal mass can't heat up enough before the solder melts.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, after some more tests, one of which consisted of baking the entire board at 240°C and hope the solder wets (cf question comments). It was actually successful, so I think you are right, and I will use an higher melting point solder paste

Answer (score 11):

I've heard bad things about desktop ovens like this.  They don't necessarily have the oomph to get the job done correctly.  Saying "I turned knob X to temperature Y and waited Z minutes"  does not mean that you have any idea what's happening to your board.  The only reliable way of knowing would be to measure, maybe with a thermocouple in contact with the board (not perfect, but likely close enough).

You're obviously reaching an adequate temperature, because the solder is melting.  It's certainly possible that your oven doesn't provide enough oomph to actually heat the board, and the solder is melting on top of cold componets. You may also be having problems with the flux.  Either the flux in the paste is past it's prime, or the heating profile you're actually getting isn't giving the flux enough time to do its job, or the flux is activating too long before you bring your solder past the melting point, and a new oxidation layer is forming.

My advice is actually to forego no-lead solder unless there is some regulatory reason why you need to work with it.  It's just harder to use- requires higher temperatures, which makes it tougher to come up with the right temp profile short of using real equipment.  You may still have problems with lead, but probably less so.

Just as an aside, regardless of the nature of your oven, if it doesn't have heat-ramp-soak control with feedback, it isn't "meant for this purpose".

Update -- given the low temp nature of the Chipquik, the comments on no-lead solder don't apply.  I think it might highlight the issue of premature and prolonged activation of flux though, if the oven is a very powerful one.  No real way of telling whether its that or a cold board, though, without measuring.  Temp crayons might shine some light on this.

Lead solder might actually help.  Flux activation temps are better documented, so the soak profiles can be tweaked to slow things down before activation to avoid oxidation.

Comment: QuickChip is a low-temperature soldering paste, working, melting around 140°C, so I don't think that the general lead-free warning applies here. I do agree about the amount of heat in the board.

Comment: @AndrejaKo -- wow -- just looked at the profiles, and that certainly is low-temp!  Is it a eutectic melt?

Comment: I'm not sure now, but I think it is. If I remember correctly (this was from few years ago), it was designed to allow very easy desoldering of large components, with the idea that you'd use it to basically replace the existing solder with this one, which takes forever to cool down, so you have lots of time to remove the component. Oh, yeah, and I missed the name in my original comment.

Comment: What the hell is a "oomph" ? Also you are right about the oven, I was told it was designed for soldering smd and I didn't question that. But then I found what a real soldering oven looks like, and I think my predecessors who bought this crap have been scamed

Answer (score 3):

There's a problem with your solder paste. May be the paste you are using is expired. If you mix it with flux it will look like mud and if put it in oven it will never melt. You can verify that paste with heat gun or solder iron. You will get the same results as in the oven. In the past I suffered the same problem and that was resolved by changing the solder paste. Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

I suspect a problem with the copper board. What about the surface, is it bare copper only, or is it covered with tin? I would try a conventional soldering iron and lead rosin-core solder to do some test joints. If the solder does not flow well, there is something wrong with the board. The surface may be oxidized or the copper areas are to large to get heated. Wipping the board with pure alcohol does not remove copper oxide from the surface, very fine abrasive paper does.

Comment: The solder flows well using an iron with leaded solder. However, i'm not supposed to use leaded solder